# Link selected combobox item back to dataset with live binding in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey

I have simple combobox linked to a firedac dataset using live binding.[image: Live Binding]

Question 1:
I'm trying to get the autokey value from the dataset for the record selected in combobox, but it seems that cursor in the dataset is not changing when you select item in combobox, so 
this: `fdmAircraftList.FieldByName('autoKey').AsString` always returns autoKey of first record of dataset. How to resolve this? Isn't live binding supposed to work like previous data aware components?
I'm not sure if it matters, but dataset is getting data through rest components( adapter, rest request and response).

Question 2: How to get dataset link from combobox? With dataware components, I know you can do something like this: `cmbAircraft.Datasource.Dataset`

Using, Delphi XE7 and this is firemonkey app.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!
To make sure that cursor is moving in dataset, livebinding needs to look like this:
[image: Correct Live Binding]